# How should I write the JavaScript code such that the output will be "first", "second" and "third"

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I'm trying to figure out a JavaScript code scope problem and I have simplified this to

```
const first = () => {
    console.log("first");
}

const second = (first) => {
    first();
    console.log("second");
}

const third = (second) => {
    second();
    console.log("third");
}
```

Based on three functions above, I am supposed to write code using only the three functions above to get the output like in console below:
first
second
third

I tried:
#1
second(first) - which returns first, second

#2
third(second(first) - which throws an error second is not a function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
third(second.bind(null, first))
```

Not that I would ever write that in the real world.
In Typescript land, bind doesn't work that well.

```
third( ()=> second(first) )
```

Could also work

Comment: easier to write `third(() => second(first))` imo

Comment: You beat me to it, I just edited my answer to include that. Though it technically creates a 4th function, so not entirely using just 3 functions